# .txt file context menu > Open is opening Registry Editor

Tags: windows-8, notepad++, windows-registry, context-menu

When I right-click `.txt` files and choose `Edit`, the file is opened in Notepad++. But when I choose `Open` (or double-click the file), I expect the same thing, but the Windows registry editor (`regedit.exe`) is being loaded.

[image: .txt file loading the Registry Editor]

The relevant registry entries are:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Apps\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,73,00,5c,00,4e,00,6f,00,74,\
  00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,5c,00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,\
  61,00,64,00,2b,00,2b,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,\
  00,22,00,00,00
```

(That is `"C:\Apps\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"` in the registry)

Why is the registry editor being loaded? Another clue is that both `.txt` and `.reg` file have the same icon in the Windows Explorer, which is the Windows Registry Editor icon. Finally, the context menu for `.reg` files does not include an option called `Merge`, see image.

[image: .reg file has no Merge option]

What is going on here and how do I fix this?

#### Update

Thanks to the answer from Kivitoe, I managed to get it partially working in `Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program`.

However, this is not the full story, because when I changed `.txt` files to use `Notepad++`, then `.reg` files stopped using the `Registry Editor` and started using `Notepad++`. So I returned and changed `.reg` to use the `Registry Editor`. This has resolved both `.txt` and `.reg` files for the `Open` command, but when I select `Edit` on a `.reg` file and choose `Notepad++`, now `.reg` files have started using **only** `Notepad++`!

Windows is confusing these two file types, and getting muddled with the `Open` and `Edit` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've set the registry editor as the default application for .txt files. Open Control Panel, then navigate to Programs > Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program. Then scroll down to and select text files and click "Change program". From here you can set Notepad or Notepad++ to open these by default.

Comment: This does the trick, but something weird is going on. When I changed `.txt` file to use `Notepad++`, then `.reg` files stopped using the `Registry Editor` and started using `Notepad++`. So I returned to `Default Programs > Associate a file type...` and changed `.reg` to use the `Registry Editor`. This has resolved both `.txt` and `.reg` files for `Open`, but when I select `Edit` on a `.reg` file and select `Notepad++`, then `.reg` files start using **only** `Notepad++`! Somehow Windows is confusing these two file types.